Count divisible elements in subarray
I am trying to solve the following exercise:

There is an array of positive integers with size N given 1 <= N <= 2*105. Each element of the array is at most 105 at all times.
After reading in these N integers, you need to support Q queries (1 <= Q <= 105).
Each query asks one of the below:

Count divisibility (represented by letter Q in input):
Find the number of elements in a subarray that are divisible by a given input value. For this query, you are given 3 integers: the left end of the subarray, the right end of the subarray, and the integer to count divisibility for.

Update (represented by letter U in input):
Change the element at some index to a new value. For this query, you are given 2 integers: the index to change and the new value.



I have a O(NQ) brute force solution but it times out. Any ideas how to solve this in better time complexity?

The input is N and Q on the first line. The next line has all the starting elements of the array separated by spaces.
The next Q lines each contain one query. The parts of the query are separated by spaces and the indexes are 0 based.
Example input:
6 4
6 5 4 3 2 1
Q 0 3 1
Q 1 4 2
U 3 8
Q 1 5 2

The ideal output is (each query for the count of divisible elements should be answered on a new line)
4
2
3

My brute force code is this (too slow however):
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using std::cin, std::cout;

    int N, Q;
    cin >> N >> Q;

    std::vector<int> array(N);
    for (int &i : array) cin >> i; // read starting array elements

    for (int q = 0; q < Q; q++) {
        char t;
        cin >> t;
        if (t == 'Q') {
            // query how many numbers in array between index left and right are divisible by num
            int left, right, num;
            cin >> left >> right >> num;
            int cnt = 0;
            for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
                if (array[i] % num == 0) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            cout << cnt << '\n'; // don't use endl when there's a lot of output
        } else {
            // simple update on one element in array
            int index, newNum;
            cin >> index >> newNum;
            array[index] = newNum;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


You have to find better algorithm, build a data structure to store information more optimally for multiple queries.

As there are "only" 9,592 prime numbers less than 100,000, having 9592 std::set might allow to have logarithmic search by query instead of linear in your brute force solution.

You can think about segment tree.

@Jarod42 I'm sorry, I don't get how to do the query on a subarray if the number we're checking for divisibility by is not a prime?

@GAVD Is there a way to do the merge of two intervals quickly? I think it takes linear time to merge the children

I know how to do this, and would be willing to give a Python implementation using https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html heavily. But I'm not willing to do this in C++. Would that be helpful?

The key idea is that for each possible divisor, you can maintain a sorted list of where numbers divisible by it are. This is rather less data than you might expect. It makes a lookup logarithmic. And an average update O(log(n)^2). Which, while not great, is likely good enough for what you need.

@btilly Python's fine. there is a builtin sorted set implementation in C++ though supporting getting elements by index and all that

@user25680598 -- You might be better off creating a "sorted set" class, where it maintains a std::vector.  Then use std::lower_bound, and std::upper_bound to do searches, return the index, and maintenance of the internal vector.

"I don't get how to do the query on a subarray if the number we're checking for divisibility by is not a prime" See Integer_factorization. i.e for query for number N, find prime numbers of N divisor: N = p1^e1 * p2^e2 * .. * pn^en, then answer of the query is the min for equivalent query for (p1, p2, .., pn). With a set::lower|upper_bound solve one query with logarithmic complexity.

@PaulMcKenzie How would you perform an update?

What's your benchmark for the time? What's the probability of input data? How are the input and output supposed to be interleaved? An instant output per individual input query, or a bulk output for a chunk of input queries?

@Red.Wave In general, for such problems, the time is the time taken to run the whole program on some input (as measured by an online judge). Probability doesn't matter; the program must be able to handle the worst case within the given input constraints (judges will test for this). And unless it's specifically enforced to be online (e.g. by XORing the input with the previous answer to get the actual input), the answers to queries just need to be output at the end in the correct order (within the time limit), so it can be solved offline if you find that easier.

@Red.Wave any input that fits the given constraints is fair game, thats nearly always how it is. I don't control the benchmark. we're allowed to "bulk output" like you said because the output is only compared with a file after the solution is done running

Interleaving IO with computation results in poorer performance. Especially with <iostream>. The offline method can produce cleaner and more optimized code. Smart choice of string conversion functions (std::to_string, std::to_chars,...) can reduce the overhead of IO. The problem doesn't seem to involve any theoretical algorithmic challenge. A simple total iteration seems to be the only option. Any effort would just make it less efficient.

@Red.Wave And yet a lot of people will complain that std::cin.tie(nullptr);, for example, is premature optimization. In general, just calling std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); std::cin.tie(nullptr); will make I/O fast enough for any problem. "A simple total iteration seems to be the only option" - This is not even close to true. O(NQ) has already been said to be too slow. Look at the answers below for more efficient solutions. If you can't think of anything, consider order statistic trees, square root decomposition, etc.

@Unmitigated I had missed a lot of possibilities.

This can be solved by applying square root decomposition to make both range queries and point updates efficient. Let's split the array into approximately √N blocks each of size √N.
For each block, we can precompute the number of elements in the block divisible by each possible query value (the integers from 1 to 100000).
We can find all factors of a number by iterating up to its square root, so we can add one element to the answer for a block in O(√(MAX_ARRAY_ELEMENT)). The precomputation for the initial array takes O(N√(MAX_ARRAY_ELEMENT)), which is acceptable since MAX_ARRAY_ELEMENT is at most 100000.
To update a value at an index, we remove the contribution of the current value at that index to its block, update the array, then add the contribution of the new element to the precomputed values for that block. This takes O(√(NEW_VALUE)).
To count the number of elements divisible by a particular number in a subarray, we can split the queried subarray into multiple segments. Some parts of the subarray might be directly covered by some blocks: there are at most √N of these and we can get the answer for each block in constant time as they are all precomputed. There are also at most two sections (at the beginning and end of the subarray) that only lie partially within a block; for these we need to use the brute force method to test all elements for divisibility, but there are only at most √N elements in each of these two blocks.
The answer is the sum of the counts of all these sections. Thus, the time complexity for one such query is O(√N).
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
constexpr int MAX_ELEM = 1e5;
int main() {
    int N, Q;
    std::cin >> N >> Q;
    int blockSize = std::sqrt(N), numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    std::vector<int> array;
    array.reserve(N);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> blockAns(numBlocks, std::vector<int>(MAX_ELEM + 1));
    auto update = [&](int idx, int delta) {
        for (int i = 1, block = idx / blockSize; i * i <= array[idx]; ++i) {
            if (auto [q, r] = std::div(array[idx], i); r == 0) {
                blockAns[block][i] += delta;
                if (q != i) blockAns[block][q] += delta;
            }
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0, x; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cin >> x;
        array.push_back(x);
        update(i, 1);
    }
    for (int q = 0; q < Q; ++q) {
        char t;
        std::cin >> t;
        if (t == 'Q') {
            int left, right, num;
            std::cin >> left >> right >> num;
            int leftBlock = left / blockSize, rightBlock = right / blockSize, count = 0;
            if (leftBlock != rightBlock) {
                for (int i = left; i < blockSize * (leftBlock + 1); ++i) 
                    count += array[i] % num == 0;
                for (int b = leftBlock + 1; b < rightBlock; ++b)
                    count += blockAns[b][num];
                for (int i = rightBlock * blockSize; i <= right; ++i)
                    count += array[i] % num == 0;
            } else {
                for (int i = left; i <= right; ++i)
                    count += array[i] % num == 0;
            }
            std::cout << count << '\n';
        } else {
            int index;
            std::cin >> index;
            update(index, -1);
            std::cin >> array[index];
            update(index, 1);
        }
    }
}


Sorry for taking so long to write this up. I will skip the I/O.
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

def build_all_factors (n):
    # We'll simplify indexing by having a useless 0.
    all_factors = [[1] for _ in range(n+1)]
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        j = i
        while j <= n:
            all_factors[j].append(i)
            j += i
    return all_factors

def query_counts (n, values, queries):
    all_factors = build_all_factors(n)

    # Build up a data structure for what multiple is where.
    factor_indexes = [SortedList() for _ in range(n+1)]
    for i in range(len(values)):
        value = values[i]
        for factor in all_factors[value]:
            factor_indexes[factor].add(i)

    for query in queries:
        if query[0] == "Q":
            _, left, right, value = query
            index_left = factor_indexes[value].bisect_left(left)
            index_right = factor_indexes[value].bisect_right(right)
            print(index_right - index_left)
        else:
            _, i, new_value = query
            # Remove the existing value.
            value = values[i]
            for factor in all_factors[value]:
                factor_indexes[factor].remove(i)
            # Update and insert
            values[i] = new_value
            for factor in all_factors[new_value]:
                factor_indexes[factor].add(i)

query_counts(10, [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [
    ['Q', 0, 3, 1],
    ['Q', 1, 4, 2],
    ['U', 3, 8],
    ['Q', 1, 4, 2],
    ])

What does space and performance look like? Let's let n be the largest integer we can have, and m be the number of values that we have.
First, the full factorization table in all_factors takes space O(n log(n)) and takes the same time to build.
The initial factor_indexes with random integers requires space O(m log(n)). Each insert takes at most O(log(n)) time. (On average it's better than that, because most factors appear at only a small number of indexes. But that's fine for an upper bound.) But even with the most pathological possible input, using a highly composite number over and over again (in your case, 83160), which means 128 * m numbers to store. Even this isn't so bad.
A Q is never more than O(log(n)) to perform. And, on random operations, is better than that because there are probably not many factors.
An U takes longer. On average we have O(log(n)) removes and inserts, each of which takes at most O(log(n)). Leading to O(log(n)^2). The pathological case is again 128 deletes and 128 inserts. Which is again not so bad. Even your worst possible update should still be faster than a naive query was before.
Of course, I've pushed the real work down to SortedList. But as you mentioned in the comments, you can use C++ containers that allow you to take the same approach.
